# Notification via iron-ajax (Polymer)

Tags: javascript, curl, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, polymer-1.0

Can we send notifications in PolymerJS using *iron-ajax* element?

Here's a sample of CURL request(works just fine):

> curl --header "Authorization: key=my_key" --header "Content-Type:
>   application/json" -d '{"to": "my_token", "notification":
>   {"title": "Hello Bro", "body": "Message Yo man"}}'
>   https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

I'm using my own values for "my_key" and "my_token" instances. In chrome it gives me something like this: [Screenshot sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSP4d.jpg)

Here's a code-sample for my iron-ajax element:

```html
<iron-ajax id="xhr"
    auto
    url="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    headers='{"Authorization": "[[my_key]]"}'
    handle-as="json"
    content-type="application/json"
    body='{"to":"[[my_token]]","notification": {"title": "Hello Bro", "body": "Message Yo man"}}' 
    method="POST">
</iron-ajax>
```

Basing on interaction with some elements on the page I'm trying to trigger the notification via JS:

```
this.$.xhr.generateRequest();
```

I'm getting this response:

```
{"multicast_id":5623718911822310219,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1489155273403695%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"}]}
```

So it appears to be successful, though this time I don't receive any notifications. Am i missing something here, or might there be a better way of achieving it in Polymer? Thank you in advance for any insights on this matter!

Comment: do you want to call some function on successfull api call?

Comment: technically I just want to receive the notification, but it's not showing with example as is, I'm curious, is that even possible to receive a gsm notification by rebuilding the mentioned curl request into iron-ajax element somehow? this could be awesome, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT WORKS as is;) You can't send notification to yourself via your own UI. Also if you're sending notification to specific app/website(atleast via desktop) - that app/website shouldn't be a current active tab in the browser(or browser shouldn't be your active app as for the receiver), this of course makes sense - but it took me some time to figure it out. Though again there is much easier way of doing this via vanilla js - you can even trigger this via your browser console (with correct parameters in place). I hope this helps someone, good luck !

```js
 function triggerNotification(key,token,title,message){
    var notification = {
      'title': title,
      'body': message
    };

    fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
      'method': 'POST',
      'headers': {'Authorization': 'key=' + key, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      'body': JSON.stringify({'notification': notification, 'to': token})
    }).then(function() {
      console.log("Response: ",arguments);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    })
}
```